# Grails Spring Security appending :8080 to URL when behind Apache proxy

Tags: grails, redirect, spring-security, port, target

In production my Grails app is running on Tomcat port 8080 and sits behind an Apache proxy; port 80. All functions work except for authentication. When a user tries logging into the app Spring Security appends :8080 to the target URL and the connection times out since the request can't be routed.

I have already set the following in config.groovy but no success:

```
    grails.serverURL = "http://domain.tld/${appName}"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = "80"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = "443"
```

The issue occurs when I try with either built-in authentication or OpenID. The app had been working well for over 6 months before my hosting provider made changes by plugged a hole and started blocking port 8080 from the outside.

I just need Spring Security to write the URL without :8080

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**
In the end the issue was with the host I was using. Something to do with Apache ProxyPass. The same application works fine on the new production VPS. Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: why not to change Tomcat's port to 80 too?

Comment: Could you post also your apache configuration? I'm also using Spring Security in an application running on Tomcat behind an Apache proxy and I don't have any problem and haven't had to set anything special on Config.groovy...

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Config.groovy file:

```
grails.server.port.http = 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider change tomcat to port 80 and forward all apache requests to port 80. Pay attention to use x-forward proto header tag by spring security.

Comment: Changing Tomcat to port 80 isn't an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in the question

[mod_rewrite not working to secure grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519295/mod-rewrite-not-working-to-secure-grails-application)

The tomcat configuration change works like a charm.